# GAE counting visitors using cookie

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, google-app-engine-python

This codes count the number of time we have visited the page, until browser is closed, using cookies. Which I am not getting. Please help

```
class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        visits = self.request.cookies.get('visits','0')
        if visits.isdigit():
            visits = int(visits) + 1
        else:
            visits= 0  

        self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' %visits)
        self.write("you've been here %s times" %visits)
```

I just want to know what is happening in these two lines

```
visits = self.request.cookies.get('visits','0')
```

and

```
self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' %visits)
```

Comment: Where do your call set_cookie?

Comment: its in 2nd line from the last

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just give you the answer, I'll help you figure out how to get it.

`self.request` and `self.response` are properties of the `MainPage` class.  To figure out what these two things are doing you need to find out where they were defined.

The `MainPage` class is a subclass of the `Handler` class.  You don't show the definition of the `Handler` class but somewhere in your code you will find that it is a subclass of `webapp2.RequestHandler`.

To find what the two lines in your code are doing, you should go read the online documentation for `webapp2`.

Comment: what about cookies.get and headers.add_header, and what is visits

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand these two lines:

```
visits = self.request.cookies.get('visits','0')
```

- self.request= requesting from the browser

  - self.request.cookies = requesting cookies[basically a dictionary] from the browser
  - self.request.cookies.get('visits')= looking for cookie whose key is visits
  - self.request.cookies.get("visits",0)= if key not found make this key value 0 and return
  - so now visits in LHS equals to 0 , as for now cookies not contain visits cookie

`self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' %visits)`

- self.response= sending from the server to browser

  - self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'visits=%s' %visits)=adding cookie to header as it is defined in header, and setting visits in the cookie